# SQL give query result table name without creating new table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which creates a dataset of two tables. I call this stored procedure from within c# as follows:

```
DataTable mytable1 = myDataSet.tables[0];
DataTable mytable2 = myDataSet.tables[1];
```

I would like to be able to pass the 'table name' into the dataset.tables function as I imagine that the stored procedure will one day return additional tables into the dataset.

There have been very similar questions asked here, such as:
[Give name to table after select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740894/give-name-to-table-after-select) and I have found other help sites like: http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

but all the answers I find end up creating additional tables or table variables. I don't want to create any new tables or variables, I simply want to create an alias for my query output.

I have tried giving my tables aliases within the SQL stored procedure but with no success. The names that appear in c# are "Table" and "Table1" respectively.

Everything else about the stored procedure functions properly, I just want it to return different names for the output tables.
I have tried the SQL code: (conditions in brackets here for simplicity)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable1 AS myTable1 WHERE (conditions)
ORDER BY (field) ASC

SELECT * FROM myTable2 INNER JOIN myTable1 ON (join on id field) WHERE (conditions)
ORDER BY (field) ASC
```

This current SQL code still results in the c# tableName field containing "Table" and "Table1".

Is it completely impossible to rename these query outputs without creating additional tables or table variables?

Comment: You'll need to work with strongly-typed datasets (see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714) to reference the items in the Tables collection by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untyped dataset( As in your case) will not give any table name to the datatable. It will be set to default. (i.e. table1, etc). As the Adapter/reader just populates the resulting rows & columns in the schema.